# How to check if an enum value changed?

Tags: java, enums

I'm new to Java and development and don't know how to do most of the stuff. So I wanter to ask you guys how to check if an enum value changed. So I have this:

```
public enum GameState {
    WAITING,
    INTRO,
    INTRO_WAIT,
    INTRO_1,
    INTRO_1_WAIT,
    LOBBY_INTRO,
    LOBBY,
    INTRO_GAME1,
    GAME1,
    INTRO_GAME2,
    GAME2;
}
```

So I want to know how to detect if an enum value changed from any of those to any of those. Hope you know what I'm try to say.
Thanks :)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by _"an enum value changed"_.  Enum values are constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean that some other class has a field `GameState state`, and you want to know when it changes from one value to another.

There's not an "automatic" way to do that. Have that other class make that field be private (which is a good idea anyway), and any time it changes it (for instance, via a `setState(GameState)` method, it can perform whatever action you want — such as calling any GameStateListener that's been registered with that class, or whatever checking mechanism you want.

It might look something like this:

```
public interface GameStateListener {
    void onChange(GameState changingFrom, GameState changingTo);
}

public class Game {
    private GameState state = WAITING; // or whatever initial value
    private final Collection<GameStateListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public void registerListener(GameStateListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void changeState(GameState newState) {
        for (GameStateListener listener : listeners) {
            listener.onChange(state, newState);
        }
        this.state = newState;
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that that code is *not* thread-safe, and making it be thread-safe would add a good deal of complexity. There are other ways to do it, too, but the above is a pretty standard pattern.